When I do a git commit to one repo, is it possible to update another repo at the same time?
I have this site, Theologicus, using mdbook. All of my writing, which are works in progress, spanning over many volumes of books.
I want to then setup subdomains for volumes that are completed. Those subdomains will be the own website and own repo. These subdomains should contain the same related appropriate content from the main domain.
For example:
theologic.us
 |
 |- Volume 1 - Im Progress
 |- Volume 2 - Completed - Subdomain volume2.theologic.us
 |- Volume 3 - In Progress
 |- Volume 4 - Im Progress

Is it possible to setup using git, GitHub actions, whatever-appropriate-tool, to where every time I push a commit to the main repo, that the subdomains automatically get updated with that same content?
Future apologies if I am not too clear. Thank you in advance for the attempt to help.

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but from what it seems you need, there are three options:

git submodules
git hooks to push changes to other repos
from your local repo, you can set it to push against multiple remotes.


@joker Thank you for the suggestions! 1) Do you have a good resource explaining git submodules? I still don't understand them. 2) git hooks makes more sense to me. This might be the way. 3) I have consider this. Is there a way to git push to all listed remotes?

Apologies for not responding sooner! Too many things have been going on. A very good resource is "Pro Git" book. Very clear explanation from the ground up. The best part is, it's for free. You can get it from here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2.

I'm not sure if I'll be able to help, but maybe if you share the topology, I might be able to assist more.

For pushing to multiple remotes, I asked gemini, and here's the response: https://g.co/gemini/share/3571fb16b02c. :)
